# How to define which SPAN to collapse first when the parent DIV has overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I've encountered with the following expectation: there is a navigation bar (div with fixed height), it has one button (encapsulated in a div) on the left (float: left), two on the right (float: right) and a title + version in the leftover middle area, aligned to left (span + span).

I would need to specify somehow that when the user re-sizes the window, then first the first span to "collapse" and apply the text-overflow: ellipsis property and when that totally disappears then the second span to disappear gradually as well.

I have no clue how to achieve this so any help comes with my automatic appreciation!

```
.middle {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#title {
  ???
}

#version {
  ???
}

<div class="container">
  <div id="button1" class="pull-left">...</div>
  <div id="button3" class="pull-right">...</div>
  <div id="button2" class="pull-right">...</div>
  <div id="middle-area" class="middle">
    <span id="title">very long title overflow should apply first</span>
    <span id="version">version 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

cheers

Comment: what about using media queries to determine the screen size and add the hidden attribute to what you want?

Comment: what do you mean @lelio-faieta by the hidden attribute? The problem is that I don't know what attribute would instruct the first span to "collapse" first :)

Comment: Hidden attribute is the Css attribute. Do you know media queries?

Comment: yes, i know the basics, i just don't know what do you mean by hidden css attribute: overflow: hidden, display: none, visibility: hidden, or something else? AFAIK there is no css property called hidden.

On the other hand: hiding completely an element is not what I try to achieve, but gradually "truncate" it while applying the text-overflow: ellipsis on the left span. When that one is completely hidden, only then to start the same ellipsis truncating on the right span.

Comment: in this case is display: none; what we are talking about. You should usse media queries to say if the screen size is less than X do not display span a. if the screen size is less than Y do not display span A and B. This is a pure css solution but again: do you know what media queries are? [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is an example

Comment: pls. see my edited comment

Answer (score 0):

You should do that with jQuery by using  `.resize()` https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Something like that:

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
        $( "#title" ).animate({
           height: "0px"
        }, 1500, function() {

             $( "#version" ).animate({
               height: "0px"
             }, 1500 );
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS media queries, it will allow you to modify css based on screen size.